# Caching static content

Tags: http, webserver, browser-cache

I'm trying to understand what's the best `Cache-Control` value to be set for static content (images, css, javascript). The issue with this is that my JavaScript/CSS is still very much in development, and whenever I make a change I want people to see changes immediately (they shouldn't have to reload their cache).

What's the best way to go about this? Should I add a `?version=1000202210` after each static request so the browser knows it's new?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a long expiration date + fingerprinting brings you maximal browser caching and at the same time the necessary flexibility to propagate changes immediately. [Google page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) has a good explanation. You can either add a fingerprint in the query string or in the path of the assets. It doesn't really matter how you do it as long as the URL changes when you want the resource to be fetched again.

Comment: Thanks! Great info that link!